# Commenting broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro

It seems I can no longer comment on questions. (Using Firefox 4 Beta 8.)

Yesterday, I could type a comment, then submitting would simply discard it. Today, "Add Comment" doesn't even work.

Anyone else experiencing this?

---

@Jarrod: Thanks. Seems the problem with displaying the comment box is only sporadic, but the submitting problem is persistent. In fact, it seems AJAX is generally quite broken. Just realised post preview isn't working now too.

Comment: Looking into it...

Comment: If you have not tried clearing your browser cache, do so. I occasionally lose site function, and this restores it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we don't support beta browsers.

That said, I don't see any other reports of commenting issues, so I'd try again in a released browser after clearing your cache.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that. Seems it's working now anyway, funnily enough!

Comment: I don't think it's safe to mark this as non-repro until a full case study is done. Considering that's a waste of resources, how about we resolve this as "not supported"?!